# In what recent model year were the Chrysler Town and Country brakes redesigned?

Tags: brakes, dodge, chrysler, town-and-country, grand-caravan

I am in the market for a minivan and the family really wants seating that can stow completely down into the floor of the van.  My understanding is that Chrysler is the only maker who has seats of this design.  That being said, I've heard that both the Chrysler Town and Country and the Dodge Grand Caravan suffer from perpetual brake wear issues.

I read somewhere that this was corrected by a redesign in later model years, however I can't seem to find definitive proof of this.  Does anyone here know when that redesign happened, if it did?  Did the redesign help with the T&C/GC brake wear issues?